# How to use Unix socket with node-redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a server running both Node.js and Redis. I am using the node-redis package to connect my Node app to Redis. The Node app and Redis are both running on a single server (same server). The [node-redis documentation](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#rediscreateclient) at GitHub states that Redis connection throughput can be increased by using a Unix socket when using a single server configuration. What is the correct way to set up Redis/node-redis to use a Unix socket?

I have tried uncommenting lines `unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock` and `unixsocketperm 700` in the **redis.conf** file, and then creating the Redis client in the Node app by specifying:

```
let client = require('redis').createClient('/var/run/redis/redis.sock');
```

After rebooting the server I see the following error in the logs:

> Error: Redis connection to /var/run/redis/redis.sock failed - connect
>   ENOENT /var/run/redis/redis.sock 0|server   |     at
>   PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1158:14)

I have also tried the following changes to **redis.conf**:

`#bind 127.0.0.1`  (commenting out the line)

`unixsocket /tmp/redis.sock`  (this is the value I see used by others; also made the corresponding change in the Node app)

`unixsocketperm 777`  (temporary relaxation of permissions to rule out permissions issues)

None of those changes resolved the error. Note that the Node app and Redis work fine together (no errors) if I do *not* attempt to use a Unix socket. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set path property to options.

```
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  path: '/var/run/redis/redis.sock'
});
```